# Is the Table in Use?

Tags: sql

How to figure out if a table is in use in SQL (on any type database)? if somebody is already using it, or have it "open" then its in use.

Comment: There are lots of kinds of "use".  Do you mean that the table is being accessed (DML = insert, update, delete, select) by a program?  Do you mean that the table structure is being modified (DDL)?  Do you mean that the table is referenced by a SQL statement somewhere in an "active" application?

Comment: Yes, accessed by a program, insert, update, delete, select or a simple BEGIN TRANSACTION (in MS SQL Server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this will give you a better result:

```
select spid
    from master..sysprocesses
    where dbid = db_id('Works') and spid <> @@spid
```

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, the correct way to find out whether someone else is using the table and will prevent you from doing whatever you want is to try doing what you want and to check whether it fails.  If the failure message indicates 'non-exclusive access' or 'table in use' or equivalent, then you guessed wrong.

If your DBMS supports table locking, you can apply a lock to the table and then do a sequence of operations - but you'll impede other people who might otherwise be trying to use it.

Note that checking in a lock table (such as syslockinfo) is both DBMS-specific and unreliable - it leads to TOCTOU (time of check, time of use) problems.

Answer (score 2):

Check for open locks on the table.

Have a look on the syslockinfo table.

Comment: Thanks that lead me to the right answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190345.aspx

For MS SQL Server